# Make association rules of a certain template

Tags: associations, data-mining, rapidminer

I got an exampleset with polinominal data and i want to create association rules with it. I do i by converting the polinominal atributes into binominal attributes using "Nominal to Binominal" then send it to "FP-Growth" and send the result to "Create Association Rules".

Lets say the attributes of the exampleSet are : attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4, attr5.

What i want to do is make sure that the association rules can only be:
premise: some value from attr1 and attr2 and attr3 and attr4
conclusion: some value from attr5

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: How about filtering the results as desired? Also, this site is for *programming* questions. Since Rapidminer is not publishing the source code of the current version, I don't think it can be considered a programming tool anymore.

Comment: but there are other RapidMiner questions here, i thought it was OK. BTW. how can i filter my result?

Comment: RapidMiner is released under a "Business Source" arrangement which apparently means that the source code will eventually be released. The closed nature of the current version doesn't preclude it being a programming environment however.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write the association rules to an XML file using the `Write` operator. You could then perhaps transform the XML using the `Process Xslt` operator (contained in the text processing extension) to include only what you needed. It would be quite a complicated process.

Comment: OK, i will try something like that